# Is $P(A \mid B) = P(A \mid B,C) + P(A \mid B , C^c)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am confused with these statements:

\begin{align}
P(A\mid B) &= P(A\mid B \cap \Omega)\\
&= P(A\mid B \cap (C \cup C^c) \\
&= P(A\mid B \cap C) + P(A\mid B \cap C^c) \quad\text{because $C$  and $C^c$ are disjoint} \\
&= P(A\mid B,C) + P(A\mid B ,C^c)
\end{align}

But according to LOTP

$$P(A\mid B) =  P(A\mid B,C) P(C\mid B) + P(A\mid B,C^c) P(C^c\mid B)$$

Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Or is it that $P(A\mid B,C) \neq P(A\mid B \cap C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong assumption is
$$
P(A \mid B\cap(C\cup C^c) ) = P(A\mid B\cap C) + P(A\mid B\cap C^c).
$$
It is true that $B\cap C$ and $B\cap C^c$ are disjoint, but this does not imply the identity above. Why do you think it would?

Note that $P(X\mid Y) = \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$ and we have
$$
\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c}
\qquad\text{but}\qquad
\frac{a}{c+c'} \neq \frac{a}{c} + \frac{a}{c'}.
$$

Comment: I got it. That identity is wrong.